# My class java has suddenly become un-serializable

Tags: java, android, serialization

One of my classes has suddenly started to complain about it being non-serializable.
I have changed some things in it but can't see anything in its definitions that could be causing it.

I get the notserializableexception on that class.

These are all the definitions at the start of the class and I can't see anything there that would cause problems.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ArrayList <Card> cards;
private ArrayList <Card> selectedCards;
private HashSet <Card> knownCards;
private ArrayList <Card> aceHighs;
private int numberOfKnownCards = 0;
private int valueOfKnownCards = 0;

public static final int sortHand = 1;
public static final int sortSelectedCards = 2;
protected int[] cardsPerSuit = {0,0,0,0}; 
private int numberOfDifferentSuits = 0;
private int[] cardsPerRank = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
private int numberOfDifferentRanks = 0;



private int whereToTakeFrom;
private int whichDiscardToTake;

private int cardCount = 0;
private int selectedCount = 0;
public  int handValue = 0;
private Deck deck;
```

Stack:

```
05-08 23:46:42.235: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1625): Shutting down VM
05-08 23:46:42.235: WARN/dalvikvm(1625): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-08 23:46:42.235: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = il.co.anykey.games.yaniv.lite.AutomatedPlayer)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1131)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1085)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:469)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1445)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:483)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityPaused(ActivityManagerNative.java:1427)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3106)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: il.co.anykey.games.yaniv.lite.Hand$1
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1854)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1696)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1660)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1153)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:420)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1251)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1587)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1854)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1696)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1660)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1153)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:420)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1251)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1215)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1215)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1587)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1854)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1696)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1660)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1153)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:420)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1251)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1215)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1587)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1854)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1696)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1660)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1153)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:420)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1251)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1215)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1587)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1854)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1696)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1660)
05-08 23:46:42.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.write
05-08 23:46:42.316: WARN/ActivityManager(63): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44d2c128 il.co.anykey.games.yaniv.lite/.YanivGameActivity}
05-08 23:46:42.335: INFO/Process(63): Sending signal. PID: 1625 SIG: 3
05-08 23:46:42.345: INFO/dalvikvm(1625): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
05-08 23:46:42.396: INFO/dalvikvm(1625): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-08 23:46:51.852: WARN/ActivityManager(63): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
05-08 23:46:52.395: WARN/ActivityManager(63): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44d2d728 il.co.anykey.games.yaniv.lite/.YanivSettingsActivity}
```

These are the two comparators I have that may be are creating the problems:

```
private Comparator<Card> byRank = new Comparator<Card>()  {

public int compare(Card c1, Card c2) {
   return c2.getCardRank()-c1.getCardRank();
}
};

private Comparator<Card> bySuitAndRank = new Comparator<Card>()  {

public int compare(Card c1, Card c2) {
   return (c1.getCardSuit()-c2.getCardSuit())*100 + c2.getCardRank()-c1.getCardRank();
}
};
```

Comment: Does it have a public, no argument constructor?

Comment: Are `Card` and `Deck` also `Serializable`?

Comment: Do you implement serializable? If so, did you change the value of `serialVersionUID`? Also, a UID of 1 isn't a very good choice ....

Comment: Yes to all. Though Card doesn't have a non-argument constructor (would be meaningless for it). However, it has always been like that.

Comment: Show us the full stack trace.  That may give some more clues as to what the problem is.

Comment: I now tried to make EVERYTHING transient but to no avail! Must be something weird going on.

Comment: @Chris Dennett: serializable classes don't need public no-args contructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the stack trace, class `il.co.anykey.games.yaniv.lite.Hand$1` (an anonymous class inside class `Hand`) is not serializable.

Comment: I did have a couple of internal classes but figured that they were the problem so I moved them out to external files. There aren't any there now.

Comment: But the stack trace does complain about that class. It's not just an internal class, it's an anonymous one. Have you checked it? It's anything of the kind `new Foo(){ /* ...methods/fields... */ }`.

Comment: That seems to have been the problem. I have changed the code so that I create the comparator when I use it rather than in advance. Works perfect. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad you solved it and thanks for the vote :) I think you can make the comparators serializable by, for instance, creating an interface `interface CompSer<T> extends Comparator<T>, Serializable` and implementing that instead of plain Comparator.

Comment: Just to expand, any time you 'put code into a variable' using `new`, as is usually the case with comparators, runnables and listeners, the java compiler creates an anonymous [inner] class representing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try marking fields that are having problems as `transient`.  Perhaps you can reconstruct them later when you deserialize.

Comment: I tried going over all the fields and marking transient a few at a time. Still didn't help.